# Present prefect or present prefect progressive

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Which one is correct?

1. I have played football for five years.
2. I have been playing football for five years.

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on context. Can you explain in more depth what you want to say, and identify why you are confused between the two options? Let us know what you've done to try to figure out the answer, as well, so we don't duplicate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are acceptable and neither is wrong. Which of the two is **more correct** will depend on the context.

Random examples:

I have played football for 5 years, but (have) never received a disciplinary suspension or even a yellow card.

I have been playing football for 5 years, and it has been great for my health and fitness.